# Inserting node in binary tree in C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I am learning C and found a basic tree implementation in my C book:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tree_node {
  int data;
  struct tree_node *left_p, *right_p;
};

struct tree_node *t_search(struct tree_node *root, int v) {

  while (root) {
    printf("Looking for %d, looking at %d\n", v, root->data);
    if (root->data == v)
      return root;
    if (root->data > v)
      root = root->left_p;
    else
      root = root->right_p;
  }

  return 0;
}

int t_insert(struct tree_node **root, int v) {

  while (*root) {
    if ((*root)->data == v)
      return 1;
    if ((*root)->data > v)
      root = &((*root)->left_p);
    else
      root = &((*root)->right_p);
  }

  if ((*root = (struct tree_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node))) == 0)
    return 2;

  (*root)->data = v;
  (*root)->left_p = 0;
  (*root)->right_p = 0;

  return 0;
}

int main(void) {

  struct tree_node *tp, *root_p = 0;
  int i;

  t_insert(&root_p, 4);
  t_insert(&root_p, 2);
  t_insert(&root_p, 6);
  t_insert(&root_p, 1);
  t_insert(&root_p, 3);
  t_insert(&root_p, 4);
  t_insert(&root_p, 7);

  for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    tp = t_search(root_p, i);
    if (tp)
      printf("%d found\n", i);
    else
      printf("%d not found\n", i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

While the code seems to be straight forward, I am having a hard time to understand the `t_insert` function. Why does it take in a `struct tree_node **root` instead of `struct tree_node *root`? `t_serach` is virtually the same code but uses only a pointer and not a pointer pointer. Maybe another example would explain the issue in a better way.

For what it's worth: I am from a Java background.

Note: Yes, I know the tree is not rebalanced upon insertion.

Comment: maybe this help, this also using pointer to pointer as argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785100/why-use-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-the-stack-when-creating-a-push-function

Comment: Your `t_insert` modifies variable `root` (set it to just inserted value). But it also have an error: instead of setting to zero pointers to neighbours of newly inserted "leaf" you should set them to point to left and right "leafs". Also you must check return value: 2 signals an error (you must signal that there's maybe not enough memory).

Comment: There are too many parentheses in `root = &((*root)->left_p);`. It will be sufficient to just write `root = &(*root)->left_p;` The author of the book *should* know this.

Comment: @wildplasser, I think those parantheses were inserted for better readability. As a novice, I would have problems to spot the operator precedence of `&(*root)->left_p`.

Comment: I presume they were. But IMHO, it is better to learn the rules of precedence the hard way. You should *know* that `->` and `[]` bind tighter than anything else, and that `=` and `,` are weaker than anything else. It may take a few monthts, but it will increase the readability in the end. Matching operator precedence is easier for the human eye+mind than matching parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some stuff we need:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct thing {
   struct thing *next;
   int value;
   };

struct thing otherthing ={ NULL, 42};
struct thing something ={ &otherthing, 13};
int forty_two = 42;

    void do_the_int(int i);
    void do_the_intp(int *ip);
    void do_the_intpp(int **ipp);
    void do_the_structp(struct thing *p);
    void do_the_structpp(struct thing **pp);
```

A function can change its arguments, but the results will not be seen by the caller, so:

```
void do_the_int(int i) {
  i = 42;
}
```

is effectively a no-op. To actually change something, the function needs a pointer to it, like in:

```
void do_the_intp(int *ip) {
  *ip = 42;
}
```

now, the value where `ip` **points to** is actually changed by the function. Next, if you want to change *a pointer* the function will need a pointer to it: *a pointer to pointer*:

```
int forty_two = 42; // global (or static)
void do_the_intpp(int **ipp) {
  *ipp = &forty_two;
}
```

For other datatypes (than int), things are not different: if you want to change a struct, the function will need a *pointer to struct*, and if the function would need to change a pointer to struct it would need a *pointer to pointer to struct*. So

```
void do_the_structp(struct thing *p) {
   p->value = 42;
}
```

will actually change something *within the struct `*p`*, and

```
void do_the_structpp(struct thing **pp) {
   *pp = (*pp)->next;
}
```

Will actually change *the pointer* located at `*pp`.

Now, let's call them:

```
int main(void) {
int zero=0
  , one=1
  , two=2;
int *the_p;
struct thing *tp, *cur;

  the_p = &two;
  tp = &something;

  printf("Before: zero=%d, one=%d, two=%d the_p=%p *the_p=%d\n"
        , zero, one, two, (void*) the_p,*the_p);
  for(cur=tp; cur; cur = cur->next) {
        printf("p=%p Next=%p Val=%d\n"
              , (void*) cur, (void*) cur->next, cur->value );
        }

  do_the_int(zero);
  do_the_intp(&one);
  do_the_intpp(&the_p);
  do_the_structp(tp);
  do_the_structpp( &tp);

  printf("After: zero=%d, one=%d, two=%d the_p=%p *the_p=%d\n"
        , zero, one, two, (void*) the_p,*the_p);
  for(cur=tp; cur; cur = cur->next) {
        printf("p=%p Next=%p Val=%d\n"
              , (void*) cur, (void*) cur->next, cur->value );
        }


  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Before: zero=0, one=1, two=2 the_p=0x7fff97a7db28 *the_p=2
p=0x601030 Next=0x601020 Val=13
p=0x601020 Next=(nil) Val=42
After: zero=0, one=42, two=2 the_p=0x601040 *the_p=42
p=0x601020 Next=(nil) Val=42
```

Comment: Great overview, let me comment a few things:
2nd example: Please add the passing int `int i; do_the_intp(&i);` or can I have a `int *ip` and pass that too?
3rd example: What is the purpose of this? I do not see a benefit doing something like this. Ex. 2 would be more appropriate.
4th example: Crystal clear.
5th example: Here I can exchange the entire struct not only its values, right? Wouldn't I need to call `free`?

Comment: Maybe I should add some typical usage for the functions. The fifth snippet actually messes with the struct, and the thing that *used to be* pointed at by `(*pp)-next` might become unreacheable. (I did not want to introduce a global, but I should have done that, on second thought)

Comment: Thanks for the update, make the issue a lot clearer but I still fail to understand really the purpose of this:

    `int forty_two = 42; // global (or static)
    void do_the_intpp(int **ipp) {
      *ipp = &forty_two;
    }` Isn't one pointer enough? Coming back to the topic. As far as I can see, if you have one pointer, you can change the content of some struct if you want to change the struct itself you will need a pointer to the pointer. Doesn't your `do_the_structpp` miss a `free(*pp)` before assigning a new value?

Comment: It is very simple: if you want to change an outside  `thing` form inside a function, the function needs a `pointer to thing` . If you want to change an outside `pointer to thing` , the function will need a `pointer to pointer to thing`. The `do_the_intpp(int **ipp){}` function wants to change an "outside" pointer, so it needs a pointer to pointer.

Comment: Understood, though that simple example with `**int` doesn't make a lot sense to me. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

It passes in a double pointer because it needs to change pointers in the process. All elements of a tree can be thought of as pointers which need to be changed when insert is called. If you don't pass in a double pointer, what you're essentially doing is copying pointer as a local variable to the function and changes have no effect when the insert function exits. Ignore me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Does this mean that I will suffer from call-by-value rather than using call-by-reference?

Comment: Yes, here, you are doing call by reference on pointers, I think. If you don't pass a double pointer (pointer to pointer), what happens is that pointer gets copied to the local function stack, function changes it on it's stack, and when it returns, no changes are made to real pointers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only read what is pointed by a pointer, your argument is of type `foo*`. If you want to change what is pointed by a pointer, your argument is of type `foo *`. But there, you want to be able to change what you point to. So, you need a pointer to your pointer, to be able to change its value.

In java, any method having as an argument a `TreeNode` is equivalent to a C function having as an argument a `tree_node*` ; hence, if you have a method with that signature :

```
// Java code
static void treeInsert (TreeNode t);
```

Within that method, you can access methods from t that can read its current status, you can even modify the state of `t`, and that state will be changed even once you left the method.

But, if you're doing something like that

```
t = null;
```

that won't have an effect once you leave the method. That means

```
// Java code
static void treeNull (TreeNode t) {
    t = null;  // Warning, local change only !
}

static void treeChange (TreeNode t) {
    t.changeState();
}

static void foo () {
    t = new TreeNode();
    t.treeChange();   // Ok, t has now an update state
    t.treeNull();     // Warning, t is not null here
}
```

You can't have the equivalent of a double pointer in java, so you can't make that work.

In C, you can do this :

```
// C code
void updateState(tree_node* t) {
    data = data + 1;  // This is nonsense, just to make the point
}

void localChangePointer(tree_node* t) {
    t = NULL;
}

void changePointer(tree_node** t) {
    free_and_clean(*t);
    *t = NULL;
}

void sillyStuff() {
    tree_node* t;
    // Initialize t
    ...

    updateState(t); // (*t).data changed
    localChangePointer(t);  // Warning : t is not null yet !
    changePointer(&t);      // This time, we gave the address of t, not t itself

    // Now t == NULL;
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `Treenode` ? Are you typedeffing pointers? Please don't; typedefs only exist to cause confusion.

Comment: Let me get this straight: If I pass a `struct *tree_node` I am able to access the struct and can change the value and the leafs but not the struct itself because the struct address is copied and am I am local-scoped? So to exchange the entire struct, I need to pass the address where the struct is stored? I thought `*tree_node` passes the address already.

Comment: @wildplasser, my mistake, this is Java code (since Michael-O talks about java background) but it wasn't clear in my answer. I'll edit that.

Comment: The reason why K&R is so terse: they did not have to *bend down* to explain things in terms of {other,newer} (C-derived) languages.

Comment: @Michael-O, no, when you pass the pointer, you can change the struct, but not the pointer to that struct. You have 3 levels : passing the struct (can't change it), passing a pointer to the struct (can change it, can't change the reference) and passing a pointer to the pointer to the struct (can change the struct and the reference, does not exist in java). I updated my answer with C code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will like such variant:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>

typedef struct btree_node{
    int data;
    struct btree_node *left, *right;
} BTree;

// get tree leaf nearest to v
BTree *bt_get(BTree *root, int v){
    if(!root) return NULL;
    int D = root->data;
    if(D == v) return root;
    if(root->data > v) return root->left;
    else return root->right;
}

// find leaf with v or nearest to it (prev)
BTree *bt_search(BTree *root, int v, BTree **prev){
    if(!root){
        if(prev) *prev = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }
    BTree *p;
    do{
        p = root;
        root = bt_get(root, v);
    }while(root && root->data != v);
    if(prev) *prev = p;
    return root;
}

BTree *bt_create_leaf(int v){
    BTree *node = calloc(1, sizeof(BTree));
    if(!node) return NULL;
    node->data = v;
    return node;
}

// insert new leaf (or leave it as is, if exists)
// return root node
BTree *bt_insert(BTree *root, int v){
    BTree *closest, *node;
    node = bt_search(root, v, &closest);
    if(node) return node; // value exists
    if(!closest) // there's no values at all!
        return bt_create_leaf(v); // create root node
    // we have a closest node to our data, so create node and insert it:
    node = bt_create_leaf(v);
    if(!node) return NULL;
    int D = closest->data;
    if(D > v) // there's no left leaf of closest node, add our node there
        closest->left = node;
    else
        closest->right = node;
    return root;
}

int main(void){
    BTree *tp, *root_p = NULL;
    int i, ins[] = {4,2,6,1,3,4,7,14,0,12};
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        if(!(root_p = bt_insert(root_p, ins[i]))) err(1, "Malloc error"); // can't insert
    for(i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        tp = bt_search(root_p, i, NULL);
        printf("%d ", i);
        if(!tp) printf("not ");
        printf("found\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// I was wrong in previous answer, correct

Answer (score 0):

Here would be doing it without double pointers. I don't see any difference.

```
int t_insert(struct tree_node *root, int v) {
  while (root) {
    if (root->data == v)
      return 1;
    if (root->data > v)
      root = &(root->left_p);
    else
      root = &(root->right_p);
  }

  if ((root = (struct tree_node *) malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node))) == 0)
    return 2;

  root->data = v;
  root->left_p = 0;
  root->right_p = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The search code at the end of the main method yields no results.

Comment: Without double pointers, insert will not work when the tree was empty prior to the call. I.e. while you create a new node as part of the insert, the caller of the method is not returned this new node.